# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS systemd start up script is not working "bad unit file setting"

Tags: server, minecraft

I've set up a minecraft server, I've made a start script which works when I execute it. I've made a .service in systemd that should start the script when the server starts, but I am having issues with the systemd part of it. Here is what I have.
[image]

```
[Unit]
Description=DeadSky minecraft server
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=mcadmin
ExecStart=/home/mcadmin/MCServer/start.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Please help me.

I've made update suggested and still having issues.

Comment: What are the issues?

Answer (score 0):

This line

`ExecStart=/home/mcadmin/MCServer/ ./start.sh` is incorrect.

It should look like this:

`ExecStart=/home/mcadmin/MCServer/start.sh`

if `start.sh` is located in the `home/mcadmin/MCServer` directory.